# GET calls for Spring REST JPA Repository code returning 404 despite using correct mappings

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying my hand at Spring REST JPA Repository code. But the simple HTTP GET and POST calls are returning 404 and there is no log in the eclipse console.
Other function calls in used classes are OK. Hence, just posting the REST Controller code:

```
package mypack;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class CRUDController
{
    @Autowired
    MasterManager Manager;  //the service layer object being used
    
    @GetMapping(value= "getall")   //getting 404 upon calling this, when it should at least return empty array of JSON objects with status msg 200?
    public List<Master> getAll()
    {
        return Manager.getall();
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value= "add")//getting 404 upon calling this, expecting status msg 200
    public void add()
    {
        Master g1= new Master("Action");
        Master g2= new Master("Adventure");
    //for the purpose of the initial testing manually creating objects and trying to persist them
        Manager.add(g1);
        Manager.add(g2);
        
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping(value= "delete/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        Manager.delete(id);
    }
    
    @PutMapping(value= "update/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public void update(@RequestBody Master master, @PathVariable int id)
    {
        Manager.update(master, genre_id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value= "getmaster/{id}")
    public String getMaster(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        return Manager.get(id);
    }
}
```

No log in the eclipse console:
[image: eclipse console]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's the exact URL you are using to call these REST endpoints? `http://<host>:<port>/<?>/getall`

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Project/add    OR  http://localhost:8080/Project/getall  as the maven project name is "Project".

Comment: Please add that to the question description as well. I added the solution to your issue.

Comment: Is it a spring boot application? If so, can you post your application.properties?

Comment: i downgraded the following dependency to version 2.4.1 from 2.4.5:<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>. This solved the problem. Dunno how...

Answer (score 0):

You need the `request mapping` at controller level to specify the context path `Project` as below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("Project")
public class CRUDController
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring adds automagic mime type handling depending on what kind of dependencies you have. If you have a json library it expects the caller to send json and accept json. And if you have an XML mapper like Jackson, it accepts only XML and talks only to clients that accepts XML.

Make sure, that the client always have the `Content-Type` Header and the `Accept` set. Otherwise spring will return with a 404 meaning "i dont know how to interpret that request or return any values to you".

Unfortunately Spring does not log why it sends a 404 in such cases on info level. You might want to set the log level to `DEBUG` in such cases.